# Declare a new log4net logger using Ninject

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api, ninject, log4net

I'm developing a Web Api application with C#, .NET Framework 4.0, Ninject 3.2.2.0 and log4net 2.0.3.

Now, I only using one logger. This is how I configure if on `NinjectConfigurator` class.

```
private void ConfigureLog4net(IKernel container)
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    var loggerForWebSite = LogManager.GetLogger("AutomationMiddlewareWebsite");
    container.Bind<ILog>().ToConstant(loggerForWebSite);
}
```

But, I need to use another logger. **Using, Ninject, how can I do it?** *I'm don't know how to declare this new logger in `NinjectConfigurator` class.*

If I declare another logger, I can't use `ILog` to bind it to my new logger. Maybe, I can use bind it with parameters...

This is my `log4net` configuration in `Web.config`.

```
<log4net xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://csharptest.net/downloads/schema/log4net.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="d:\\MyProject.Web.Api.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value=".yyyyMMdd.lo\g" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
      <countDirection value="1" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level [%thread] %logger - %message%newline%exception" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="MyProjectWebsite">
      <level value="DEBUG" />
    </logger>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could bind multiple loggers `.ToConstant(...)` and use [Contextual Binding facilities](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding) like `.WhenInjectedInto<SomeClass>()`.

```
Bind<Ilog>().ToConstant(logger1)
    .WhenInjectedInto<Class1>();
```

But if you need to inject the logger into a lot of classes that would present a lot of work and very poor maintainability.

In that case you can opt to use the `ToMethod(..)` binding or use a [provider](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers,-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context) and create the logger depending on the context, like so:

```
Bind<ILog>().ToMethod(context =>
                 LogManager.GetLogger(context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type));
```

(`context.Request.ParentContext.Plan.Type` is the Type `ILog` is injected into)

of course you can use some elaborate scheme to determine which logger to use based on the class name, the class assembly, the class namespace,.. you name it.

If you want only one or two specific loggers you can use the contextual binding (`When(...)`) approach and if more, you can use the `ToMethod(...)` or `IProvider` approach.